# aws sdk lambda list functions returning empty functions array

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

```js
var params = {
      MasterRegion: "us-east-1",
      FunctionVersion: "ALL",
      //Marker: '',

      MaxItems: 10
    };
    lambda.listFunctions(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
      else console.log("Lambdas list ", data);
    });
```

This code returns empty functions array in the response. Even though there are lambdas in the region.
However, the params object:

```js
var params = {
      //MasterRegion: "us-east-1",
      //FunctionVersion: "ALL",
      //Marker: '',
      MaxItems: 10
    };
```

Returns lambdas in the region.
What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1931

This issue explains the problem here.